# How do I get milliseconds since midnight UTC in C?

Tags: c, time.h

The time function in time.h gives milliseconds since the epoch.

Comment: Actually, the time() function gives the time in seconds, not milliseconds, since the epoch (and it ignores leap seconds).

Answer (score 7):

This is a simple way:

```
time_t seconds_since_midnight = time(NULL) % 86400;
```

To get approximate milliseconds since midnight, multiply `seconds_since_midnight` by 1000.

If you need more resolution (consider whether you really do), you will have to use another function such as `gettimeofday()`.

Answer (score 7):

This is the precise way:

```
struct timeval tv;
int msec = -1;
if (gettimeofday(&tv, NULL) == 0)
{
    msec = ((tv.tv_sec % 86400) * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000);
}
```

That will store into `msec` the number of milliseconds since midnight.
(Or -1 if there was an error getting the time.)

Although it's usually a bad idea to store time-values in an `int`, I'm being a little cavalier and assuming `int` is at least 32-bit, and can easily accommodate the range (-1) to 86,400,000.

But I don't know if it's worth all the effort.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your code, according to the C that I know. Maybe you should have declared `msec` beforehand, also used `else`.

Answer (score 5):

You use gettimeofday(2) which is defined in POSIX.1 and BSD.

It returns seconds and microseconds as defined in struct timeval from sys/time.h.

Answer (score 0):

You will find `C` code examples for getting time and converting it to various formats [here](http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleB1.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at   gmtime()          Converts directly to Coordinated Universal Time  (UTC)...