# C milliseconds since midnight

Tags: c, time.h

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get milliseconds since midnight UTC in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072455/how-do-i-get-milliseconds-since-midnight-utc-in-c)

I'm trying to get the time elapsed in milliseconds between the start of the current day (12:00:00.0000 AM) to the current time. What would I use in time.h to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Do you actually need the current _time of day_ to this resolution, or are you just timing something?  There isn't a standard way in C to get the time of day with this accuracy.

Comment: I'm trying to code an accurate decimal time clock and if I program it based off of seconds, it skips every now and then as seen here: http://www.minkukel.com/en/time/metric_clock.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the time of day since epoch:

```
struct timeval time;
gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
```

If you mean the system time:

```
time_t t;
time(&t);
```

Comment: `gettimeofday` is Posix not std C, and may or may not be available.  It is not in time.h (at least not on my system).  `time` is similar, but is generally at one second resolution, so even less useful.

Answer (score 0):

While I realize you asked for milliseconds, this is how you can get that in seconds:

```
time(NULL)%(24*60*60)
```

Answer (score 0):

[How do I get milliseconds since midnight UTC in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072455/how-do-i-get-milliseconds-since-midnight-utc-in-c/1072506#1072506)

> This is a simple way:
>
> ```
> time_t seconds_since_midnight = time(NULL) % 86400;
> ```
>
> To get approximate milliseconds since
>   midnight, multiply
>   `seconds_since_midnight` by 1000.
>
> If you need more resolution (consider
>   whether you really do), you will have
>   to use another function such as
>   `gettimeofday()`.