# Nanoseconds since midnight

Tags: c, linux, time

I have a timestamp representing nanoseconds since midnight. I would like to calculate the number of nanoseconds (right now) since midnight, to subtract the two timestamps and measure the latency. I would like to do this using the fastest operations.

The target platform is x86-64 Linux, Clang compiler, no old Kernel or hardware, I don't care about daylight saving, there are no round cases to cover etc.

I understand:

```
struct timespec now;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
```

will return the number of seconds since Epoch and the number of nanoseconds after the last second.

I therefore think I just need to create a time point representing midnight, extract the number of seconds since Epoch from midnight and then do:

```
now_nanos = (((now.seconds_since_epoch) - (midnight.seconds_since_epoch)) x 1 billion) + now.nanos_since_last_second
```

How do I create a time point representing midnight, to extract the number of seconds since Epoch?

I have seen examples using `mktime()` returning a `time_t` but I wasn't sure how to extract the seconds since Epoch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get nanoseconds since midnight with the lowest latency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58905600/608639)

Comment: @jww nope, that's a C++ question.

Comment: @jww hmmI think this should have C only,

Comment: @jww now this is C only, let the other be C++ only, no need to dupe anything. Let the other have whatever <boost> there would be :P

Comment: @Antti - Sorry, I don't see a material difference between the two questions. This question is tagged C and C++. The cited dup is tagged C++ and uses the same C data structures and system calls. The [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58907934/nanoseconds-since-midnight?noredirect=1#comment104078674_58907994) seems to indicate the same: *"Might as well post that here [cited dup] and i'll accept that too..."*.

Comment: @jww well it works in C++ too. It is not a duplicate of a C++ question, because as soon as it becomes full of C++ stuff it is not going to help people who use C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the current time with `time`.  Then pass the result of that to `localtime_r` to get the time broken up into its components pieces.  Zero out the hours, miniutes, and seconds, then use `mktime` to switch back to seconds since the epoch.

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm tm;
localtime_r(&now, &tm);
tm.tm_sec = 0;
tm.tm_min = 0;
tm.tm_hour = 0;
time_t start_of_day = mktime(&tm);
```

Comment: @user997112 a `time_t` holds the number of seconds since the epoch.  When you convert to nanoseconds, you may want to explicitly cast to `uint64_t` to make sure you don't overflow / wraparound.

Comment: All good, thank you sir. Just waiting before I can accept your answer.

Comment: Might as well post that here and i'll accept that too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58905600/get-nanoseconds-since-midnight-with-the-lowest-latency

Comment: On days when DST switches, this approach can fail as `now` and midnight may exist with different `.is_dst` settings.  Even though OP says "I don't care about daylight saving,", setting `tm.tm_isdst = -1;` prior to `mktime()` is a good mitigating step.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Why would tm.tm_isdst = -1 mitigate that? How does it work?

Comment: @user997112 `.tm_isdst`: [a negative value
       means that mktime() should (...) attempt to determine whether DST is in effect at the specified time..](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3.html)